# How to print separate url for each venue id?

Tags: python, pandas, foursquare

I have extracted this venue_id list:

```
0     4b92802ff964a5209cfe33e3
1     4e6ddd03fa768e6cee3d6485
2     51d81d66498e78da5b1601af
3     4d5fe18a9be02c0fc2e5de74
4     4d021cca9f9ea143b1648da9
5     4dce6fd2d164679b8cfec4dd
6     5469d96f498e07ba3182673f
```

Now I want to generate 6 url using this venue_id. For example:

'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4b92802ff964a5209cfe33e3?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=20180604'

I am using following code to do it:

```
url2 = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{}?client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}'.format(venue_id_list, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VERSION)
for i in venue_id_list:
    print (url2)
```

But the result is coming in this way:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/0     4b92802ff964a5209cfe33e3
1     4e6ddd03fa768e6cee3d6485
2     51d81d66498e78da5b1601af
3     4d5fe18a9be02c0fc2e5de74
4     4d021cca9f9ea143b1648da9
5     4dce6fd2d164679b8cfec4dd
6     5469d96f498e07ba3182673f
```

whereas I want it to come like this:

'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4b92802ff964a5209cfe33e3?client_id=XXXXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXX&v=20180604'

'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4e6ddd03fa768e6cee3d6485?client_id=XXXXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXX&v=20180604'

and so on... where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
venue_id_list=[
"4b92802ff964a5209cfe33e3",
"4e6ddd03fa768e6cee3d6485",
"51d81d66498e78da5b1601af",
"4d5fe18a9be02c0fc2e5de74",
"4d021cca9f9ea143b1648da9",
"4dce6fd2d164679b8cfec4dd",
"5469d96f498e07ba3182673f"]

url2 = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{}?client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}'
for venue in venue_id_list:
    print (url2.format(venue, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VERSION))
```

first you create your modular string `url2` and then for each `venue in venue_id_list` you apply the format

Answer (score 0):

## i think you have to keep client_id and client_Secret static and only pass venue as dynamic to form your string, see if the below code helps.

l = ['4b92802ff964a5209cfe33e3','4e6ddd03fa768e6cee3d6485','51d81d66498e78da5b1601af','4d5fe18a9be02c0fc2e5de74','4d021cca9f9ea143b1648da9', 
'4dce6fd2d164679b8cfec4dd','5469d96f498e07ba3182673f']

cl_id = '???????????'
cl_sec = '?????????????&v=20180604'

url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/?client_id=&client_secret='

for i in l:
    print('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{}?client_id={}&client_secret={}'.format(i,cl_id,cl_sec))